# How to reconcile Salesforce SSO using WS-Federation and REST API using OAuth 2.0?

Tags: oauth, salesforce, single-sign-on

I am developing web application which consists of a Silverlight application and a REST API.  An optional use case is that the customer may also want to integrate with Salesforce.  By "integrate" I mean utilize SSO with Salesforce when logging into my application as well as access data via Salesforce's REST API.  The current hurdle I can't seem to get over is that SSO uses WS-Federation while Salesforce's REST API uses OAuth 2.0.  What is the best way to being these two authentication mechanisms together?

My knee-jerk reaction was for my Federation Provider STS to acquire an OAuth access token from Salesforce and add it as a claim to the security token received from Salesforce's Identity Provider STS, but I think this might require me to write a custom STS.  I'd rather not do that.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but comes up often, so ...
There is now information on how to do this here

[Configuring-SSO-to-SharePoint](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Configuring-SSO-to-SharePoint)

This approach uses WS-Fed.